# Hide img tag if no image added from admin side

Tags: php, image, src

I want to be able to hide the img src tag if no image is added from the admin side

I have already tried onerror attribute

This is what I have tried

```
if ($row['postImage'] !=''){
    echo "<p><img src='".$url.$row['postImage']."' class='img-responsive' onerror='this.style.display='none';'></p>";
}
```

The code above just outputs the following

```
<img src='https://www.it-doneright.co.uk/blog/images/' class='img-responsive' onerror='this.style.display='none';'>
```

Update: Got it working with the following code

```
 if ($row['postImage']!='images/' && $row['postImage']!=''){
 echo "<p><img src='".$url.$row['postImage']."' class='img-responsive'> 
 </p>"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your postImage field should have a 'null' default value, in that way it will be enough to test for true or false.
Regards.

Comment: I have set the postImage to NULL as a default value in the db table but unsure on the coding to be honest

Comment: With a null default value in DB, your condition should be as ```if ($row['postImage']){
    echo "<p><img src='".$url.$row['postImage']."' class='img-responsive' onerror='this.style.display='none';'></p>";
}```

Comment: I tried that code but the broken image placeholder is still showing and the img tag is still showing within the source code

Comment: Mhm it sounds strange for me, I've just replicated your code using two variants for testing '$row['postImage'` variable and none is displayed. You can see it here https://faridsilva.com/test-image.php.

Comment: Managed to sort the issue now and just about to update the original code with the working code